# i am using angular 11 i want to do a project but i got errors

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, ubuntu-20.04

```
        ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json'
See "/tmp/ng-lQbnUK/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

and when i create the project i got those errors

```
installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.3: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...p2zraxyqI5tT/g9UTBUgK'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/safa/.npm/_logs/2021-02-15T15_46_03_482Z-debug.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: What project? Where is the code?

Comment: i want to open a new project but i can't

Comment: ng serve doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Delete `node modules` folder & `package-lock.json` file.

Run again

```
npm install

ng serve
```

if that doesn't work, upgrade the dependencies with

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node-modules folder
2. Then npm i

if error presist again then
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular